# Unify xlabel and ylabel in a subplot with seaborn regplots as subplots

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the below code that draws two seaborn regplots next to each other. I'm having trouble showing the unified xlabel and ylabel. It is currently writing whatever the column name of the df is (so `var1` for xlabel and `var2` for ylabel).

I want to customize the labels. I tried `ax1.set_xlabel("New custom label")` and it didn't work. Not sure what else to try.

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 6), ncols=2, sharey=True)
f.suptitle("Unified Title of Graph")
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

x_jit = 0.075
y_jit = 0.05

ax1.set_title("Mini Title 1")
ax1.set_xlim([0,1])
ax1.set_ylim([0,100])
sns.regplot(df1['var1'], df1['var2'],ax=ax1, marker='o', color='#39ad48', label="label1", scatter=True, x_jitter=x_jit, y_jitter=y_jit, x_ci=95)


ax2.set_title('Mini Title 2')
ax2.set_xlim([0,1.01])
sns.regplot(df2['var1'], df2['var2'],ax=ax2, marker='o', color='#d9544d', label="label2", scatter=True, x_jitter=x_jit, y_jitter=y_jit,x_ci=95) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: I am able to overwrite the labels of an example `sns.regplot` using `ax.set_xlabel` using Python 2.7. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BKS, when did you try `.set_label` (before or after `regplot`)? it might be that you need to change the labels _after_ you call `regplot`.

Comment: @tom this worked! thanks! but now it is putting it on every subplot, how can I have one centered xlabel across both graphs?

Comment: Then you probably don't want an xlabel, since they are tied to a subplot axes instance. You could try adding some text manually to the figure with `plt.figtext`